# VM disk size libation in specific regions

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to increase disk size of my VM and apparently its not allowed ti increase to more than 250GB in my region. Is this known problem? It's not very much. Any suggestions how to increase more?

```
 Failed to update disk instance-1: Quota 'SSD_TOTAL_GB' exceeded. Limit: 250.0 in region europe-west4.
```

Answer (score 1):

There's different quotas per **project** and per **region** that may apply.
I suggest you to take a look at your actual usage as described in the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#checking_your_quota), substituting the relevant values:

`gcloud compute project-info describe --project <PROJECT_ID>`

`gcloud compute regions describe <REGION>`

In your case, you should look for the `SSD_TOTAL_GB` metric in the results.

If you need an increase in the quota, you can also request it as specified [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota) or accessing directly to your console via this [link](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas/details;servicem=compute.googleapis.com;metricm=compute.googleapis.com%2Fssd_total_storage;limitIdm=1%2F%7Bproject%7D;allQuotasPageStatem=(%22expandableQuotasTable%22:(%22f%22:%22%255B%257B_22k_22_3A_22_22_2C_22t_22_3A10_2C_22v_22_3A_22_5C_22ssd_5C_22_22%257D%255D%22))).